# how to avoid blank area treeview node clicking?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, outlook-addin

I am working on a regular WinForm Outlook Addin and I have created a Treeview using DrawNode event, The tree is working as expected but there is a glitch in node clicking, only the green region is clickable and the half node gets non responsive. [image]

When I use the `MouseDown` event the whole area gets clickable including the blank space right next to the node. 
 But to restrict this blank clicking I am using a logic with the help of `TreeViewHitTestLocations` I am checking if the clicked location is the `RightOfLabel` then don't do anything but unfortunately this doesn't give me a precise result, it somehow gets confuse and takes right half of the label(Node) as the blank space and doesn't get clicked.

Note: I think this all happened because I played with DrawNode method and while keeping the distance between label and workspace icon the application underneath assumes that the label gets finish within the green portion so the red portion gets left as a blank space. This is just my assumption based on all the naïve things I have done with the method.

Need help to resolve this issue if someone can guide me to a fix. Thanks

```
 void treeview_mousedown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

        TreeNode nodeClicked;

        // if arrow up/down will be excluded from the mousedown event

        var hitTest = this.HitTest(e.Location);
        if (hitTest.Location == TreeViewHitTestLocations.PlusMinus)
            return;

        if (hitTest.Location == TreeViewHitTestLocations.RightOfLabel)
            return;

        // Get the node clicked on
        nodeClicked = this.GetNodeAt(e.X, e.Y);

        // Was the node clicked on?
        if (!(nodeClicked == null))
            this.SelectedNode = nodeClicked;       

    }
```

Below is the treeview drawnode method I am using:

```
void treeview_DrawNode(object sender, DrawTreeNodeEventArgs e)
    {
        Rectangle nodeRect = e.Node.Bounds;

        // below location is the expand and collapse icon location
        Point ptExpand = new Point(nodeRect.Location.X - 7, nodeRect.Location.Y + 5);

        Image expandImg = null;

        // check the below condition for nodes with child nodes and nodes without child nodes
        if ( e.Node.Nodes.Count < 1)
            expandImg = global::myresource.OfficeAddin.Controls.Resource.search;
        else if (e.Node.IsExpanded && e.Node.Nodes.Count > 1)
            expandImg = global::myresource.OfficeAddin.Controls.Resource.down_arrow_icon;
        else 
            expandImg = global::myresource.OfficeAddin.Controls.Resource.right_arrow_icon;

        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(expandImg);
        IntPtr imgPtr = g.GetHdc();
        g.ReleaseHdc();
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(expandImg, ptExpand);

        // draw node icon
        Point ptNodeIcon = new Point(nodeRect.Location.X - 4, nodeRect.Location.Y + 2);
        Image nodeImg = global::myresource.OfficeAddin.Controls.Resource.folder_icon_16px;
        g = Graphics.FromImage(nodeImg);
        imgPtr = g.GetHdc();
        g.ReleaseHdc();
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(nodeImg, ptNodeIcon);


        // draw node text
        Font nodeFont = e.Node.NodeFont;

        if (e.Node.NodeFont != null)
        {
            nodeFont = e.Node.NodeFont;
        } else {
            nodeFont = new System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI", 10F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        }

        // set the forecolor
        Color forecolor = e.Node.ForeColor;

        // color same as the font color
        string strSelectedColor = @"#505050";
        Color selectedColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(strSelectedColor);
        SolidBrush selectedTreeBrush = new SolidBrush(selectedColor);


        //Inflate to not be cut
        Rectangle textRect = nodeRect;

        //below value controls the width of the text if given less then, long texts will come in multiple lines
        textRect.Width += 150;

        // below value controls the over all width of the node, if given less all the things will get sqeeze
        e.Graphics.DrawString(e.Node.Text, nodeFont, selectedTreeBrush , Rectangle.Inflate(textRect, -20, 0));

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is right, you can check it by marking the bounds at drawing, for example:

```
TreeNodeStates state = e.State;
bool isFocused = (state & TreeNodeStates.Focused) == TreeNodeStates.Focused;
if (isFocused)
    ControlPaint.DrawFocusRectangle(e.Graphics, e.Bounds, foreColor, backColor);
```

Your code has more problems:

**Issue 1: Images**

If you use icons for nodes use the `TreeView.ImageList` and `TreeNode.ImageKey` properties. Otherwise, no space will be allocated for the image at drawing. In this case you can use `TreeViewDrawMode.OwnerDrawText` `DrawMode`.

**Issue 2: Fonts**

Do not use other font than the font of the node or the tree because it can have unexpected size. If this *SegoeUI* font is a default one use it at your `TreeView` instance instead. Then you can obtain the required font like this:

```
Font font = e.Node.NodeFont ?? e.Node.TreeView.Font;
```

**Issue 3: Texts**

You use `Graphics.DrawString` for drawing texts, which uses GDI+. However, starting with .NET 2.0 the default text rendering method is by GDI, unless `CompatibleTextRendering` property of a control is true. They produce slightly different text sizes.

To use GDI, for which the size of a label is calculated use the `TextRenderer` class instead:

```
TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, e.Node.Text, font, e.Bounds, foreColor, TextFormatFlags.GlyphOverhangPadding | TextFormatFlags.SingleLine | TextFormatFlags.EndEllipsis | TextFormatFlags.NoPrefix);
```